# Problem with Touchpad scroll

Tags: 12.10, vmware, synaptics

I've installed Virtually **Ubuntu 12.10** on my **Toshiba** laptop with **Vmware** 9.0 
it works good, but my Touchpad scrolling doesn't work anymore

My Question is:
Where I can download a driver for my Synaptic touchpad to run mouse scrolling?

Or any other commands/solutions , I tried some of commands, but they didn't make any sense.

Thank you :)

Comment: Since my answer below didn't work, you probably need to install drivers as you first thought.  Open a terminal (Ctrl + t) and run `lsusb`.  Can you *edit it* the output to your question please?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing the scrolling settings in System Settings?

Open System Setting from the Dash.  It will look like this:

[image]

Navigate to "Mouse and Touchpad" and switch to the "Touchpad" tab.

[image]

Change the radio button under scrolling from "Disabled" to "Edge Scrolling" or "Two-Finger Scrolling".

[image]

Comment: Touchpad tab not found :(

[see this](http://www.unimasr.net/ums/upload/files/2013/Mar/UniMasr.com_ccbbcccc4b9dc5ddf195c96b8c723a3c.png)
@Seth